# ROS meta-package ros-melodic-desktop-full doesn't include mav packages

Tags: ros

Why doesn't the installation of the meta-package `ros-melodic-desktop-full` on Ubuntu 18.04 Melodic include the packages `ros-melodic-mav-msgs`, `ros-melodic-mav-msgs` and `ros-melodic-mav-planning-msgs`?

Comment: Why should it? desktop-full is a collection of what most users need and you have to make a cutoff somewhere.

Comment: I see. Shall I remove this question, then?

Comment: No. Maybe someone who decided what to include has a real answer. (Would be interesting to know how this was decided.)

Answer (score 2):

The melodic `desktop-full` metapackages is defined in [REP 150](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html) with several of the other core metapackages.